# PowerShell SmtpClient unable to authenticate

Tags: powershell, smtpclient

I'm trying to send an email with PowerShell using Rack Space's emailsrvr service. I should add, I'm a PHP guy, so PowerShell is way outside my normal work scope. Code as follows (variables are all set above this snippet):

```
$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMessage.From = $emailFrom

foreach ($addr in $emailTo) {
    $emailMessage.To.Add($addr)
}

$emailMessage.Subject = $subject
$emailMessage.Body = $emailContent

$smtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient('smtp.emailsrvr.com', '587')
$smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $false;
$smtpClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($smtpUser, $smtpPass);
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

> Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Transaction failed.
>   The server response was: 5.7.1 : Recipient
>   address rejected: Access denied" At C:\my_test_script.ps1:24
>   char:5
>   +     $SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException

From what I understand - this is because the SMTP Client is not properly authenticating with RackSpace and relaying is being denied.

I decided to try telnet to see what's what:

```
220 smtp2.relay.ord1d.emailsrvr.com ESMTP - VA Code Section 18.2-152.3:1 forbids use of this system for unsolicited bulk electronic mail (Spam)
ehlo mydomain.com
250-smtp2.relay.ord1d.emailsrvr.com
250-SIZE 75000000
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 STARTTLS
```

I think the trouble is that PowerShell, being a Microsoft product, wants to use a more secure auth method than PLAIN or LOGIN.

Is there anyway I can force PowerShell to use an auth method that RackSpace supports? I was looking at a few solutions, but they seems to be C# based as the code is not recognized by PowerShell.

Comment: seems that email server uses STARTTLS, which means, you should use $smtpClient.EnableSsl = $true
See RFC 3207 for more information.

Comment: I have tried both. This is the non-secure port.. so it is a bit odd to see STARTTLS there.

Answer (score 0):

As MS .NET API browser states, "System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient is now obsolete API".
"SmtpClient and its network of types are poorly designed, we strongly recommend you use https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit and https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit instead"

You could try this.